# shift_right python using for loops

Tags: python

The question is to write a `shift_right` function so that it shifts every element in the list to the right. For instance, if the list is

```
L = ['a','b','c','d']
```

`shift_right(L)` should be `['d','a','b','c']`.

This is what I tried; my output is `['d','a','a','a']`:

```
def shift_right(L):
    last_item = L[-1]

    for i in range(1, len(L)):
        L[i] = L[i-1]

    L[0] = last_item
```

Comment: That's actually a rotate right, not a shift. David, below, has the right code for doing it in-place.

Answer (score 3):

I'd implement it like this:

```
def shift_right(L):
    if len(L) > 0:
        L.insert(0, L.pop())
```

As Lee correctly comments, this is a rotate operation rather then a shift.

Comment: Alternatively since insert and pop are having to effectively resize and reallocate the list and to avoid the len check to avoid the valueerror on pop, then I would be tempted by `L[:] = L[-1:] + L [:-1]` and return None to keep with the Python principle that mutations do not return the object being mutated

Comment: @JonClements: but that solution creates two temporary lists, combines them to make a third temporary list, and *then* assigns the temporary...that seems less efficient than just resize & reallocate (especially because Python probably won't shrink the actual list storage).

Comment: Thanks a lot David and Jon

Comment: @nneonneo however - it scales better... should these kind of operations be frequent - of course the OP shiuld be using a deque ...

Answer (score 2):

I'll add this in for completeness.

If you are shifting several at at time you can use something like

```
def rotate(L, n):
    if len(L) is not 0:
        shift = n % len(L)
        L[:shift], L[shift:] = L[-shift:], L[:-shift]
```

If you are doing this often throughout your program, it could be worthwhile to use a deque.
You can convert your list to a deque like this:

```
from collections import deque
L = deque(L)
```

then to rotate it n spaces to the right, you can use

```
L.rotate(n)
```

If you want to convert it back into a list, you can do

```
L = list(L)
```

It is better to avoid converting back and forth, since it takes as much time as several rotations in the list.
Deques work best when you are accessing, adding, and deleting around their beginnings and ends.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the answer for the question. Its as follows.

```
def shift_right(L):
    last_item = L[-1]
    for i in range(1, len(L)):
        L[len(L) - i] = L[len(L) - i - 1]
    L[0] = last_item
```